# CSS issue: How to prevent div moving out of position when scrolling

Tags: css, html, positioning

CSS newb here. I'm modifying the CSS of a blog template, but I've run into an issue where the divs containing the blog title/comments/tags will move out of their original position when scrolling down the page. I've tried many attempts to make it so that they'd always retain their original position, but I haven't been successful yet. Any input/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @John B. The script changing the position to fixed is around line 105 in template.js

```
 $(activeProject+ " .project_rail").css({"position":"fixed","top":feedHeaderHeight});
```

Comment: bingo! it's javascript that's doing it. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the css property

```
position:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

theres some script on your page thats applying positon: fixed; to its parent div(.project-rail) when you scroll.  if you change the class name that will stop the script action.  Or you could remove the script.  If you change the class name though you will have to reapply the style rules to the new class.